# MongoDB $lookup aggregation resulting in nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections that are in many-to-one relationship (multiple hosts' http services often serve the 'same' e.g. DNS-level load balancing).
I'm trying to build a query returning the relevant documents (from two collections) merged into one.

hosts collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60aa2485332483cb4f5e7122"),
    "ip" : "1.2.3.4",
    "services" : [
        {
            "proto" : "tcp",
            "port" : "22",
            "status" : "open",
            "reason" : "syn-ack",
            "ttl" : 53,
        },
        {
            "proto" : "tcp",
            "port" : "80",
            "status" : "open",
            "reason" : "syn-ack",
            "ttl" : 51,
            "http" : [
                ObjectId("60aa64c67d0bf23ce47c530c")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version" : 4,
    "last_scanned" : 1621573240.730579,
```

https collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60aa64c67d0bf23ce47c530c"),
    "vhost" : "test.com",
    "paths" : [
        {
            "path" : "/admin",
            "code" : 200
        },
        {
            "path" : "/stuff",
            "code" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to write a lookup where the output is a combination of these two collections. So far I was able to get the https document into a top-level array in hosts:

```
db.hosts.aggregate([                                                                                                                                       
  {                                                                             
    $lookup:                                                                    
        {                                                                       
            from: "https",                                                      
            localField: "services.http",                                        
            foreignField: "_id",                                                
            as: 'http'                                                 
        }                                                                       
  }                                                                             
]).pretty()
```

Which ends up as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60aa2485332483cb4f5e7122"),
    "ip" : "1.2.3.4",
    "services" : [
        {
            "proto" : "tcp",
            "port" : "22",
            "status" : "open",
            "reason" : "syn-ack",
            "ttl" : 53,
        },
        {
            "proto" : "tcp",
            "port" : "80",
            "status" : "open",
            "reason" : "syn-ack",
            "ttl" : 51,
            "http" : [
                ObjectId("60aa64c67d0bf23ce47c530c")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "http" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60aa64c67d0bf23ce47c530c"),
            "vhost" : "test.com",
            "paths" : [
                {
                    "path" : "/admin",
                    "code" : 200
                },
                {
                    "path" : "/stuff",
                    "code" : 200
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    "version" : 4,
    "last_scanned" : 1621573240.730579
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I can't move the "http" field to the place where it's ObjectId was found by lookup (services.$.http). I was trying to modify the 'as' field of $lookup in various ways without success.

Is it even possible to point to lower levels of a nested document with 'as'?
Any workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct services array
- `$lookup` with `https` and set `as` as `services.http`
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `services` array and set other required fields

```
db.hosts.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$services" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "https",
      localField: "services.http",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "services.http"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      ip: { $first: "$ip" },
      services: { $push: "$services" },
      version: { $first: "$version" },
      last_scanned: { $first: "$last_scanned" }
    }
  }
]).pretty()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kbeSpmLJ7oX)

---

Second option without `$unwind`,

- `$lookup` with `https` collection
- `$map` to iterate loop of `services` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `http` result that is from lookup
- `$ifNull` will return empty [] if field is null / not found
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `services` and filtered `http` array
- `http` array result is not needed now so remove it using `$$REMOVE`

```
db.hosts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "https",
      localField: "services.http",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "http"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      services: {
        $map: {
          input: "$services",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$s",
              {
                http: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$http",
                    cond: {
                      $in: ["$$this._id", { $ifNull: ["$$s.http", []] }]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      http: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VCG5pkhg8XM)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do what I want. I was on the right track, just did not use group properly. Going back to experiment further...

Comment: The only downside I see is that each field in 'hosts' needs to be added to $group, so the document's flexibility depends on the aggregation pipeline. It's not a big problem atm, but is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: not other option using when we use $unwind & $gruoup, but there is an option without $unwind, it will cause performance issues when there are lots of data.

Comment: see i have added second option without $unwind.